# Cakephp:How to validate fields to accept a range of values for a specific entry

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i have a table which accepts Grade(eg A,B,C...) and the other one accepts Marks(0-100).I want each grade to accept a specified range of marks.Eg A must accept any marks in the range 75-100.

If a user enters a grade,it should only accept a mark in the range of that grade.My two fields are as follows.

```
$mygrade =array('A'=>'A','B'=>'B','C'=>'C','D'=>'D','E'=>'E','U'=>'U');
        echo $this->Form->label('Grade: ');


echo $this->Form->label('Mark(%): ');
echo $this->Form->input("ApplicantOlevelQualification.mark.$s",array('label'=>''));
```

Please help guys i'm stuck

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correct, you're trying to validate your marks with the grade that is selected.

I am assuming, ApplicantOlevelQualification is your model.
Create a model and include validation:

```
<?php
class ApplicantOlevelQualification extends AppModel {
    public $validate = array(
        'grade' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('inList', array('A', 'B')),
                'message' => 'Not in range.',
            )
        ),
        'marks' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('validMarks'),
                'message' => 'Marks does not meet the criteria.',
            ),
        )
    );

    function validMarks($check) {
        //Access $this->data and $check to compare your marks and grade..
    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps.